# How can I save only some elements of a List in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, list, object, arraylist

I tried to do this, but the add in the line arrayList.add give me an error

```
    List <Recipes.Results> list;
    ArrayList <Recipes.Results> arrayList;
    

    arrayList = new ArrayList<Recipes.Results>();

    for (Recipes.Results re: list){
        arrayList.add(re.getId(), re.getTitle(), re.getImage());
    }
```

Im trying to create an arraylist whit only 3 elements of the List, that it contains 5. Example, the List contain a class Results whit id, image, title, nutrients, typeimage. I want only to pass id,image and title to the arraylist. How can I do that?

Comment: Please provide more detail about what you are trying to do and what difficulty it presents.

Comment: @khelwood im trying to create an arraylist whit only some elements of a list. Example, the List contain a class Results whit id, image, title, nutrients. I want to pass only id,image and title to the arraylist.

Comment: @tmm: what _type_ of element do you expect to have in the resulting `ArrayList`?  That's really the root of why you're having problems.  Is it possible to have a `Recipes.Results` that has only those three values?  Or do you need to create a new class that only has those three values?

Comment: @LouisWasserman i want the 3 strings that contains id, title, image. Recipes.Results need more value so i should create a fast new class whit only the 3 param?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  You must have a single element type that contains any values you care about.

Comment: @LouisWasserman                                                                                                  
     arrayList = new ArrayList<RecipesTemp>();

        for (Recipes.Results re: list){
            temp = new RecipesTemp(re.getId(), re.getTitle(), re.getImage());
            arrayList.add(temp);
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `add` method requires a `Recipes.Results` object as a parameter. You are passing in a set of member variables instead. Before the call to the `add` method, put in some condition or processing to determine what object to add to the `ArrayList`. You mat need to define a new class that is similar to `Recipes.Results` that contains just a subset of the data, or you may wish to construct new `Recipes.Results` objects that contain 1 or more null fields.